# MongoDb filter to get objecs between two dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get notifications between two dates using MongoDB;
there are 7 days between two dates and using the function below to get data, but I'm always error code 500, any idea how to fix it?

Sample data added below.

**Function**

```
exports.getNotifications = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const notifications = await notification.find({
      createdAt: { $gte: ISODate(date), $lt: ISODate(expires) },
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ notifications });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      ...error,
    });
  }
};
```

**Sample Data**

```
  {
"_id": {
"$oid": "613200ad493dae19e881e031"
},
"date": {
"$date": "2021-09-03T11:01:47.972Z"
},
"expireDate": {
"$date": "2021-09-10T11:01:47.972Z"
},
"seenBy": [],
"title": "Social Karanlık Mod!",
"coverImage": "https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Karanlık-Mod-1.png",
"actionType": "basic",
"context": "Profil sekmesindeki butondan karanlık ve aydınlık mod arasında geçiş yapabilirsiniz!",
"__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Please, post the error message on your question.

Comment: no error message just {}

Comment: `console.log(error)` before returning 500 and you may get the stack trace ...

Comment: prints nothing sorry

Comment: could you add sample data to question

Comment: sample data added below

Comment: I don see "createdAt" key in Sample Data or "expireDate" in Function

Comment: You're right, i was using wrong name for variable but also;
expireDate: { $lte: new Date() }, this is returning empty list

Comment: okay using $gt instead of $lte fixed it, thanks a lot for help!